# How to make a ListActivity item with many Views in inside clickable

Tags: android, click, listactivity

this probably is a popular question so sorry if I'm asking the obvious but I couldn't find an answer. Basically I've got a ListActivity which is being populated by LinearLayout which has many Views in it. I just want the bars to be clickable and selectable as at the moment they do not respond to clicks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. Since my class signature is this:

```
public class ResultsPage extends ListActivity {
```

I needed to implement this method to make it work:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement OnClickListener as part of class definition and register the linearlayout (or any widget) to listener. snippet as follows

```
LinearLayout content;       
content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.<layoutid>);
content.setOnClickListener(this);
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.<layoutid>:
        //TODO your actions
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but the content.setOnClickListener(this); line is causing my app to be be forced closed by android. I'm going to search for more info, thanks.

Comment: You need to implement OnClickListener to the Activity . Snippet as follows public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener